# How can this piece of C++ code get memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I wrote some C++ code to implement my own stack. But when I use `valgrind` to check it, it said that there may be memory leak. I checked for so long but still can not find it.

This is the code:

```
#ifndef RE_STACK_H
#define RE_STACK_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include "general.h"

template <typename T>
class Stack {
private:
    T* bottom;
    T* top;
    T* sentinel;
    uint32 size;
public:
    Stack(uint32 size = 30);
    ~Stack();
    void push(const T&);
    T pop();
    void expand();
};

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(uint32 size) :size(size){
    bottom = top = static_cast<T*>(malloc(size * sizeof(T)));
    sentinel = bottom + size * sizeof(T);
}

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack() {
    while (top-- != bottom){
        top->~T();
    }
    free(bottom);
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& item){
    if(top == sentinel){
        expand();
    }
    new(top++)T(item);
}

template <typename T>
T Stack<T>::pop() {
    if(bottom == top){
        return 0;
    }
    T re = *--top;
    top->~T();
    return re;
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::expand() {
    size *= 2;
    uint32 temp = top - bottom;
    bottom = static_cast<T*>(realloc(bottom, size * sizeof(T)));
    top = bottom + temp;
    sentinel = bottom + size * sizeof(T);
}
#endif //RE_STACK_H




#include <iostream>
#include "NTL/Stack.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error information from `valgrind`:

```
==33519== HEAP SUMMARY:
==33519==     in use at exit: 22,216 bytes in 190 blocks
==33519==   total heap usage: 256 allocs, 66 frees, 27,992 bytes allocated
==33519== 
==33519== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 58 of 63
==33519==    at 0x10000817C: malloc_zone_malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==33519==    by 0x1005E1EFD: _objc_copyClassNamesForImage (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005D5182: protocols() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005D5093: readClass(objc_class*, bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005D2C13: gc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005DA24E: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005E7132: layout_string_create (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005D583C: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005D5300: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005D52E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005D52E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519==    by 0x1005D52E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==33519== 
==33519== LEAK SUMMARY:
==33519==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==33519==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==33519==      possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks
==33519==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==33519==         suppressed: 20,152 bytes in 189 blocks
==33519== 
==33519== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==33519== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 18 from 18)
```

I have viewed several comments, and I want to explain:

1. I use `malloc()` and `free()` rather than `new` and `delete`, because I want to separate the process of memory allocation and class construction, and you can see in my destructor, I free memory there. And every time I `pop()` a item, I use the class's destructor to make sure it is properly destructed, but **I did not free the memory, since I may use it later**.
2. Thanks to Joachim Pileborg,  `sentinel = bottom + size * sizeof(T);` should be changed to `sentinel = bottom + size;`, but this is not the reason why `valgrind` says **2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 58 of 63**
3. I know I did not follow the 3/5 rules, in fact I didn't finish the code and I am going write the copy constructor and assign operator later, and I just want to test the code when it is not big.
4. **Please do not say the code is rubbish when you just have a glance and notice I use `malloc()`; if you ever see the source code of STL, you will see that the way how allocator works**

Comment: Notice in the Valgrind output that none of your code seems to be referenced? That means you don't have a memory leak. The "leak" is most likely a false positive, from some initialization code that allocates memory dynamically that's supposed to live for the life-time of the program.

Comment: There are many problems with this code, for starters: don't use `malloc` in C++ code, also don't call destructors (`~T()`) by hand. I would advise you to consolut a tutorial regarding memory management, in particular, regarding `new / delete`

Comment: Calling destructors doesn't destroy the object. The destructor is a function like any other. You need to deallocate the object (using `free` if you use malloc) which will then call the destructor

Comment: You have no copy constructor and no assignment operator -- See the [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @hfhc2 While I agree on `malloc`/`free`, there are places when calling a destructor is okay, like when doing manual memory management (which is done here).

Comment: @hfhc2, @adnan_e: calling placement `new` and explicit destructors on `malloc`ed memory is fine.

Comment: To the OP: The initialization of `sentinel` doesn't look right to me, shouldn't it be only `sentinel = bottom + size`?

Comment: @adnan_e The destructor is exactly what destroys the object; memory allocation is a separate thing. And `free` does not call the destructor.

Comment: Werrrrghhh... `malloc`? Why?!

Comment: `realloc` wouldn't call the copy constructor (if address changes)(neither the destructor).

Comment: How/where is your code actually being used? Your `main()` function is just `return 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I think it's because `valgrind`. I don't know why, even I write just as simple as follow codes, I got an error...

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, thanks to those people who help me to find out the mistakes :

1. `sentinel` need only add size...
2. `realloc` can not help me to call destructor.